# How to know the gcc version used to build the linux?

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, openwrt

I use OpenWRT. it's a linux distribution for embedded systems

I want to know the gcc version used to compile the linux

I made some researchs in the net but without results.

I tried to execute these commands for some existing binary  in the linux OpenWRT (like wget)

```
strings -a <default binary> | grep "GCC"
strings -a <default binary> | grep "gcc"
```

But I did not get any result

even the

```
strings -a  /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 | grep  "gcc"
strings -a /lib/libuClibc-0.9.30.1.so | grep   "gcc"
```

does not give any result

Are there a way to know used gcc to build the whole linux (For both user space and kernel space)?

Comment: The kernel or userspace programs?

Comment: There is no way to determine which gcc is used to build the "whole linux".  Each executable may have been built with a different gcc, or even a library within the executable was built with one gcc, or it may not have even been a C program at all (C++, Fortran, Java (with gcj), etc).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For programs, it appears in the `.comment` section of ELF executables, if your system is using ELF.

```
$ cat main.c
int main() { }
$ gcc main.c
$ objdump -s -j .comment a.out

a.out:     file format elf64-x86-64

Contents of section .comment:
 0000 00474343 3a202844 65626961 6e20342e  .GCC: (Debian 4.
 0010 372e322d 35292034 2e372e32 00474343  7.2-5) 4.7.2.GCC
 0020 3a202844 65626961 6e20342e 342e372d  : (Debian 4.4.7-
 0030 33292034 2e342e37 00                 3) 4.4.7.
```

The compiler used to compile the kernel is available from the string in `/proc/version`, for example:

```
$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.8.5 (...) (gcc version 4.7.2 (Debian 4.7.2-5) ) ...
```

### A major caveat

The `.comment` section is optional.  Many distributions will strip it from the executable when the executable is bundled into a package.  The section will be placed in a separate debug package.

For example, on my system:

```
$ objdump -s -j .comment /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4.2.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4.2.0:     file format elf64-x86-64

objdump: section '.comment' mentioned in a -j option, but not found in any input
file
```

After installing the `libcurl3-dbg` package, we get an image with the stripped sections by following the GNU debug link:

```
$ objdump -s -j .comment  \
    /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/8c/4ae0ad17a4e76bab47c487047490061bd49de3.debug

/usr/lib/debug/.build-id/8c/4ae0ad17a4e76bab47c487047490061bd49de3.debug:
    file format elf64-x86-64

Contents of section .comment:
 0000 4743433a 20284465 6269616e 20342e37  GCC: (Debian 4.7
 0010 2e322d35 2920342e 372e3200           .2-5) 4.7.2.
```

Comment: any way the `cat /proc/version` helped me (+1) to find out the gcc used to build the kernel and I think it's the same used to build the user space for OpenWRT

Comment: @MOHAMED: I didn't notice the `-a`.  Anyway, your binaries are probably stripped, you'll have to get the version from the debug files.

Comment: where I can find the debug files ?

Comment: @MOHAMED: It depends on the distribution.  They don't necessarily exist, and might not exist for all packages.

Answer (score 1):

For building the OpenWRT workspace your main gcc is used:

```
gcc --version
```

For cross compile all the needed tools are located under you openwrt build dir.

The gcc used during the compile can be found in the `staging directory` of OpenWRT. Go to you openwrt home directory and look for the `toolchain` directory under the staging dir. Here you will find a `bin` directory, where all the cross-compile tools are located.
For example for `ar71xx`:

```
$ ./staging_dir/toolchain-mips_r2_gcc-4.6-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/bin/mips-openwrt-linux-gcc --version
mips-openwrt-linux-gcc (OpenWrt/Linaro GCC 4.6-2013.05 r57678) 4.6.4
```